# ¿Por que se usa * cuando debería ser *&?

Tags: c++

Tengo este código pero en la declaración de las funciones no debería ser Nodo*&? pero en vez de eso se esta usando solo el *, no se debería usar el *&? ya que tengo entendido que el *& se usa para cuando deseas modificar el árbol y con el * no entiendo como funciona ya que el árbol se modifica y no se esta usando el *&, Gracias.[image: Aqui el codigo:]

Comment: El código debe ir como texto por favor, así la comunidad no deberá reescribir (*en caso de ser necesario*) todo tu código

Comment: El `*&` son 2 cosas. `*` un puntero, y `&` una referencia. Si no vas a modificar el puntero, no hay razón para pasarlo por referencia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un poco confuso pero son dos conceptos diferentes que estás manejando:

1. Paso de parámetros a una función
2. Punteros (o apuntadores)

Sobre el **Paso de parámetros a una función**, vale mencionar que hay dos formas de pasarlos:

**A. Parámetros por valor:** en estos, los parámetros reciben copias de los valores que se les pasan. Su particularidad es que, las variables que se le pasan a la función, mantienen sus valores correspondientes, una vez salen de ella (no se modifican dentro de la función).

**B. Parámetros por referencia:** en estos, los parámetros reciben la dirección de memoria de los argumentos pasados. Su particularidad es que aquí sí se modifican los valores que se le pasan a la función. Los parámetros por referencia hacen uso del símbolo **&** en la cabecera del prototipo y en la cabecera de la definición de la función.

Sobre los **Punteros (o apuntadores)**: estos son variables que se utilizan para almacenar direcciones de memoria.

Habiendo recordado eso, importante saber que "**Los punteros en c ++ se pueden pasar por valor o por referencia**".

En tu caso, si pasas un puntero por valor como en:

```
void eliminar(Nodo *arbol)
```

Entonces la función *eliminar* solo puede cambiar el contenido de la memoria a la que **arbol** apunta (pueden haber cambios en esa posición de memoria) pero arbol nunca apuntará a una dirección de memoria diferente cuando finalice la función.

Por el contrario, si pasas un puntero por referencia como en:

```
void eliminar(Nodo *& arbol)
```

Entonces la función *eliminar* puede hacer que **arbol** apunte a una ubicación diferente en la memoria, y al finalizar la función la variable seguirá con esa modificación.

**En conclusión**: cuando usas solo * estás pasando la variable por valor (lo cual te garantiza que siempre apuntará a la misma dirección de memoria); mientras que si usas *& estarás pasando la variable por referencia, lo cual te permitirá que tu variable apunte a una dirección de memoria diferente a la que tenía. *Vale mencionar que en cualquiera de los dos casos, al ser apuntadores, aunque la dirección de memoria permanezca igual, si es posible modificar el contenido guardado en esas posiciones de memoria.*

Espero haberte ayudado!